# Why request.getRequestDispatcher doesn't work?

Tags: http, jsp, request, response

I have a main JSP and process JSP. In process jsp I am committing the response and forward the response to a success page.

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

I am able to commit the response at the server side. Process jsp is also able to forward the response to success JSP. 
But the url shows for example:  http://process.jsp?param1=value1&parm2=value2

I want my output to display a clean as in url http://success.jsp

Please Note: This works perfectly fine for Java Servlet, i just tried it. 
I am using only JSP instead of Java servelet, since this is our project requirement.

Can anyone suggest me a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) Is supposed to forward both the request and the response objects to another resource within the server. No response goes back to the client when you do a `forward()`  and this is why the client shows the same initial URL.

For the client to show another URL you could use [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29). This does go back to the client making it do a new request to the URL you want. So change it to:

```
response.sendRedirect("success.jsp").
```

Remember not to commit the response before doing this or you'll get an `IllegalStateException`

As to why you say that on a Servlet works, I'm not sure why, but is not how `forward()` is supposed to work, and JSP are compiled to Servlets so in the end they should behave the same.

Comment: Well, I agree with you that ideally it should behave the same way. But somehow, I can get the servelet class file to submit & redirect correctly with a clean URL of success.jsp. While, when I use the process jsp, it forwards to the success.jsp, but url still shows process.jsp with list of parameters in the url (I wanted a clean URL after the forward).

Comment: Which container are you using?